# Javascript regex to remove clutter between matching words

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to remove spaces between some words that appear next to each other, how can I achieve this?

Cosider the following:

```
str = "Z =A= =B= =C= =D= Z";
str = str.replace(/(=\w+=)\s+(=\w+=)/g, "$1$2");
```

I would expect `"Z =A==B==C==D= Z"` (all matches joined together) but instead I get `"Z =A==B= =C==D= Z"` (space between `=B=` and `=C=`) as `=A=` + `=B=` are considered a match and `=C=` + `=D=` also, but `=B=` + `=C=` not since `=B=` was already a match with `=A=`.

How should I rephrase my regex to achieve it?

**Update**

The actual matches I'm using are "mime-words", for example `=?ISO-8859-1?B?dGVzdA==?=` and the regex I use for mathcing these is `/=\?[^?]+\?[QqBb]\?[^?]+\?=/`

I want to strip spaces between these mime words occurances in a string, for example

```
str= "hello =?ISO-8859-1?B?dGVzdA==?= =?ISO-8859-1?B?aG93?= =?ISO-8859-1?B?YXJlIHlvdQ==?=?"
```

should become to

```
"hello =?ISO-8859-1?B?dGVzdA==?==?ISO-8859-1?B?aG93?==?ISO-8859-1?B?YXJlIHlvdQ==?=?"
```

Comment: Why not simply `str.replace(/= =/g, '')`?

Comment: I have a complicated regex to match these words, the =A= was just a simplified example and I need to match the complete word not just the beginnig or end

Comment: The reason for this is that even when setting the regex to global, it won't match overlapping matches. Can you describe your needs in a little more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use positive lookahead:

```
str= "hello =?ISO-8859-1?B?dGVzdA==?= =?ISO-8859-1?B?aG93?= =?ISO-8859-1?B?YXJlIHlvdQ==?=?"
res = str.replace(/(=\?[^?]+\?[QqBb]\?[^?]+\?=)\s+(?==\?[^?]+\?[QqBb]\?[^?]+\?=)/g, "$1");
```

**output:**

```
"hello =?ISO-8859-1?B?dGVzdA==?==?ISO-8859-1?B?aG93?==?ISO-8859-1?B?YXJlIHlvdQ==?=?"
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply add another replace statement like this after first replace:

```
str = str.replace(/(=\w+==\w+=)\s+(=\w+==\w+=)/g, "$1$2");
```

**Update:** I think this can simply be done in one simple regex liek this:

```
str= "hello =?ISO-8859-1?B?dGVzdA==?= =?ISO-8859-1?B?aG93?= =?ISO-8859-1?B?YXJlIHlvdQ==?=?";
str = str.replace(/= =/g, "==");
```

**OUTPUT**

```
hello =?ISO-8859-1?B?dGVzdA==?==?ISO-8859-1?B?aG93?==?ISO-8859-1?B?YXJlIHlvdQ==?=?
```